# Couldnt use buttons after using TranslateAnimation?

Tags: android, translate-animation

I have been working on the following code

```
    Animation animation1= new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-250);
    animation1.setDuration(1000);
  animation1.setFillAfter(true);
     rom.startAnimation(animation1);
```

The translate is working just fine ,but i couldnt use clicklistener after this translate .
Is it possible to use it.
Please someone help me?

Comment: when you use an animation , the button place is in his first place ( not at the place after the end of the animation ), try to click at the first place of your button and you will see the click event on your button , so to resolve this problem , i suggest to add an `AnimationListener ` , and in the `onAnimationEnd()` , try to change the place of your Button to place it exactly at the last place after the animation , i wish you understand me ,Sorry for my English :)

Comment: Can you tell me how can I change the place of my button!

Answer (score 0):

You can call setFillAfter(true) on the Animation itself, before you run it.
This will apply the new coords to the View after the animation is complete.

```
anim.setFillAfter(true);
viewToAnimate.startAnimation(anim);
```

If that doesn't work, you can try setting margins on the view when the animation is complete. Create an AnimationListener and set it for the Animation. Then change the views position using margins in the onComplete method.

```
final View viewToAnimate = ...;
final int finalX = ...;
final int finalY = ...;

anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
            {

            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
            { 
            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
            {
            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
            {
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
                lp.setMargins(finalX, finalY, 0, 0);
                viewToAnimate.setLayoutParams(lp);
                viewToAnimate.requestLayout();
            }
        });
viewToAnimate.startAnimation(anim);
```

The above code assume that your view is contained within a FrameLayout (hence the FrameLayout.LayoutParams code)

Another thing you can try is to Layout the view again with the new coords once the animation is complete.

```
viewToAnimate.layout(finalX, finalY, finalX + viewWidth, finalY + viewHeight);
viewToAnimate.requestLayout();
```

Try each one of these 3 methods out and see which one works for you.
Hopefully the setFillAfter(true) method will work as it's the easiest.

EDIT: Oops - i didn't notice you were calling setFillAfter already. Looks like that doesn't work, so try one of the other 2 methods

Comment: Sorry but this is not correct. The animation doesn't actually move the button, it still stays at its original coordinates, see the SDK.

Comment: Um, yes that is what I am saying. That's why you have to use margins to move the view after the animation is complete, or call the views layout method again when the animation is complete. Only then will the view move. See my answer above...